# Exception calling "SetAccessRule" with "1" argument(s) ::: Powershell Error

Tags: powershell

I get an error with my Powershell script where I am trying to give a folder "Total Control". I can give Total Control to a Domain/Users account, but I can't seem to get it to work for a ComputerName\Users account. This is important to allow other software being installed to work on various computers in our organization (they all have a ComputerName\Users account in the Security tab). I want to give Total Control to [ComputerName\Users] account.

Screenprint below shows DomainUsers/Account my script could create, and below it the ComputerName\Account I can't reference in any way to give Total Control -- In this example, "Users(OHAIBMG00B7KP\Users)", triggers an error.

[image: Security Tab Screenprint]

This script works to create Account and Total Control permissions for a folder

```
$directory = "C:\Program Files (x86)\CAREWare"
$domainName = "DHS"
$group = 'Domain Users'
$inherit = [system.security.accesscontrol.InheritanceFlags]"ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit"
$propagation = [system.security.accesscontrol.PropagationFlags]"None"
$acl = (Get-Item $directory).GetAccessControl("Access")
$user = "{0}\{1}" -f "$domainName", $group
$user.trim()
$access = "FullControl"
$accessType = "Allow"
$accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule -ArgumentList @("$user","$access", "$inherit", "$propagation", "$accessType")
$acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule)
set-acl $directory $acl
```

This is the error when I try to change the three lines below to reference ComputerName\Users.

```
$directory = "C:\Program Files (x86)\CAREWare"
$domainName = $env:computername
$group = 'Users'

Exception calling "SetAccessRule" with "1" argument(s): "Some or all identity references could not be translated."
At line:1 char:1
+ $acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IdentityNotMappedException
```

I can't seem to get PowerShell to find and return anything about the ComputerName\Users group, but it is there in the Security Tab of the Folder Properties.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whe searching for the error message `Some or all identity references could not be translated` similar questions have been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26892490/some-or-all-identity-references-could-not-be-translated-c-sharp), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27719035/folder-permissions-some-or-all-identity-references-could-not-be-translated) and [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/682e88c0-e044-46f9-8b5d-55f185e85a1a/directory-acl-berechtigung?forum=visualcsharpde&prof=required) where the answers were that you have to use the SID instead of `COMPUTER\Users` when creating the `FileSystemAccessRule`. The SID can be retrieved via `GetPrinicpalBySamAccountName`.

Comment: Ok, your "here, here, and here" looks like good stuff for me to study. Might be the solution. But at this time I am also realizing that I don't want to create a new group or user, just give permissions to an existing one. So I deleted and undeleted this post because I noticed an answer (yours) was coming in. Since you really have helped to answer my posted question, I am accepting this answer and using it to study more on the subject. thank you very much

Comment: I did notice that all your solutions are for .NET code. . . . In the title of my question I specify PowerShell

Comment: @JustJohn both PowerShell and C# run on .NET, so you can use the same calls in both programming languages. So when you see a `C#` example calling `new System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule()` you can use the same in Powershell by issuing `New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule` (or [`System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule]::new()` when using PoSH 5+).

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a really old thread but the solutions is removing the inheritance and propagation from your access rule for files.

For Folders:

$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($Identity, $rights, $inheritance, $propagation, $accessControl)

For Files:

$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($Identity, $rights, $accessControl)

Answer (score 0):

Per my tests, you must use `"BUILTIN\Users"` instead of `"computerName\Users"`.

Example below works for me:

```
$nvsFolder = "C:\ProgramData\folder"
$Acl = Get-Acl $nvsFolder
$Ar = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("BUILTIN\Users", "FullControl", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
$Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)
Set-Acl $nvsFolder $Acl
```